ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mixture: The specified module could not be found. When I try use a .dll file and import from my .pyx file
I am trying to call a C function in Python using Cython from a set of C header files that I got from an R package. The goal is to replicate the R code in Python. R makes the .dll files when I built the package, so naturally I just used the src folder with all the .c, .h, .o, and .dll files when working in Python.
I'm trying to call one of the functions that is defined in the .dll file with Cython, but I only get the error:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mixture: The specified module could not be found.


Here's my code:
test.py
import numpy as np

from mixture import py_print_matrix
if __name__ == "__main__":

    description = "My Matrix"
    rows = 3
    cols = 3
    lda = 3
    matrix = np.array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6], [7.7, 8.8, 9.9]])

    py_print_matrix(description, matrix, lda)


mixture.pyx
cdef extern from "src/functions.h":
    void print_matrix(const char* desc, int m, int n, double* a, int lda)

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def py_print_matrix(desc, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a, lda):
    
    cdef bytes desc_bytes = desc.encode()
    cdef char* c_desc = desc_bytes

    cdef int m = a.shape[0]
    cdef int n = a.shape[1]


    a = np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(a), dtype=np.float64)
    print_matrix(c_desc, m, n, <double*>a.data, lda)


setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe"

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name="mixture",
        sources=["mixture.pyx"],
        include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
        library_dirs=["src"],
        libraries=["TFunHDDC", "funclustweight"]

    )
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)   
)


For more context I'm storing all of the .c, .h, .o, and .dll files in a folder called src in the working directory.
I've also tried including the absolute path but I always get the same error. I'm using a 64 bit Python, and my .dll files are also 64 bit. Even when I store all the files in the same directory, I still get the same error. It doesn't tell me what .dll file isn't loading, so I'm not sure what to do.

https://pypi.org/project/dlltracer/ is a fairly useful tool that may help. Plus something like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies
